# Fully Convolutional Network, Training Error

Tags: tensorflow

I apologize that I'm not good at English.

I'm trying to build my own Fully Convolutional Network using TensorFlow.
But I have difficulties on training this model with my own image data, whereas the MNIST data worked properly.

Here is my FCN model code: (**Not using pre-trained or pre-bulit model**)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
```

## Loading MNIST Data

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

images_flatten = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])

images = tf.reshape(images_flatten, [-1,28,28,1]) # CNN deals with 3 dimensions
labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32) # Dropout Ratio
```

## Convolutional Layers

```
# Conv. Layer #1
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 1, 4], stddev = 0.1))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([4], stddev = 0.1))    
FMA = tf.nn.conv2d(images, W1, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
# FMA stands for Fused Multiply Add, which means convolution
RELU = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(FMA, b1))
POOL = tf.nn.max_pool(RELU, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding='SAME')

# Conv. Layer #2
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 4, 8], stddev = 0.1))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([8], stddev = 0.1))    
FMA = tf.nn.conv2d(POOL, W2, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
RELU = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(FMA, b2))
POOL = tf.nn.max_pool(RELU, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding='SAME')

# Conv. Layer #3
W3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([7, 7, 8, 16], stddev = 0.1))
b3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([16], stddev = 0.1))   
FMA = tf.nn.conv2d(POOL, W3, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='VALID')
RELU = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(FMA, b3))

# Dropout
Dropout = tf.nn.dropout(RELU, keep_prob)

# Conv. Layer #4
W4 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1, 1, 16, 10], stddev = 0.1))
b4 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([10], stddev = 0.1))   
FMA = tf.nn.conv2d(Dropout, W4, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
LAST_RELU = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(FMA, b4))
```

> Summary: [Conv-ReLU-Pool] - [Conv-ReLU-Pool] - [Conv-ReLU] - [Dropout] - [Conv-ReLU]

## Define Loss, Accuracy

```
prediction = tf.squeeze(LAST_RELU) 
# Because FCN returns (1 x 1 x class_num) in training

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction, labels))
# First arg is 'logits=' and the other one is 'labels='

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001)    
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

label_max = tf.argmax(labels, 1)
pred_max = tf.argmax(prediction, 1)
correct_pred = tf.equal(pred_max, label_max)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))
```

## Training Model

```
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(10000):
   image_batch, label_batch = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
   sess.run(train, feed_dict={images: image_batch, labels: label_batch, keep_prob: 0.8})
   if i % 10 == 0:
       tr = sess.run([loss, accuracy], feed_dict={images: image_batch, labels: label_batch, keep_prob: 1.0})
       print("Step %d, Loss %g, Accuracy %g" % (i, tr[0], tr[1]))
```

> Loss: 0.784 (Approximately)
>
> Accuracy: 94.8% (Approximately)

The problem is that, training this model with MNIST data worked very well, but with my own data, loss is always same(0.6319), and the output layer is always 0.

There is no difference with the code, excepting for the third convolutional layer's filter size. This filter size and input size which is compressed by previous pooling layers, must have same width & height. That's why the filter size in this layer is [7,7].

What is wrong with my model?..

The only different code between two cases (MNIST, my own data) is:

## Placeholder

My own data has (128 x 64 x 1) and the label is 'eyes', 'not_eyes'

```
images = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 128, 64, 1])
labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, 2])
```

## 3rd Convolutional Layer

```
W3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([32, 16, 8, 16], stddev = 0.1))
```

## Feeding (Batch)

```
image_data, label_data = input_data.get_batch(TRAINING_FILE, 10)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

for i in range(10000):
    image_batch, label_batch = sess.run([image_data, label_data])
    sess.run(train, feed_dict={images: image_batch, labels: label_batch, keep_prob: 0.8})
    if i % 10 == 0: ... # Validation part is almost same, too...

coord.request_stop()
coord.join(threads)
```

Here "input_data" is an another python file in the same directory, and "get_batch(TRAINING_FILE, 10)" is the function that returns batch data. The code is:

```
def get_input_queue(txtfile_name):
    images = []
    labels = [] 

    for line in open(txtfile_name, 'r'): # Here txt file has data's path, label, label number
        cols = re.split(',|\n', line)
        labels.append(int(cols[2]))
        images.append(tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.read_file(cols[0]), channels = 1)) 

    input_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([images, labels], shuffle = True)
    return input_queue

def get_batch(txtfile_name, batch_size):
    input_queue = get_input_queue(txtfile_name)
    image = input_queue[0]
    label = input_queue[1]

    image = tf.reshape(image, [128, 64, 1])

    batch_image, batch_label = tf.train.batch([image, label], batch_size)
    batch_label_one_hot = tf.one_hot(tf.to_int64(batch_label), 2, on_value=1.0, off_value=0.0)
    return batch_image, batch_label_one_hot
```

It seems not to have any problem .... :( Please Help me..!!

Comment: Try scaling your inputs (-1 to 1) and set the `stddev` of your weights to a lower value like 0.01. The `output always zero` points to `dead` ReLUs.

Comment: What does 'scaling inputs (-1 to 1)' mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your inputs scaled appropriately?. The jpegs are in [0-255] range and it needs to be scaled to [-1 - 1]. You can try:

```
 image = tf.reshape(image, [128, 64, 1])
 image = tf.scalar_mul((1.0/255), image)
 image = tf.subtract(image, 0.5)
 image = tf.multiply(image, 2.0)
```

Comment: Thank you! I learned that images sometimes need to be normalized.

Comment: Did it fx the problem you were facing?

Comment: Um.. After I did it, loss and accuracy seem to be calculated properly, but finally accuracy becomes 198 or even more over than 200. However, the loss problem (which was always 0.6139) was solved. :)

Comment: Never mind! It works. Thank you so much. Now I realize that data and the pre-processing is definitely important to train the model.

Answer (score 0):

What is the accuracy you are getting with your model for MNIST? It would be helpful if you post the code. Are you using the trained model to evaluate the output for your own data.

A general suggestion on setting up the convolution model is provided [here](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/).
Here is the model suggestion according to the article  :-

> INPUT -> [[CONV -> RELU]*N -> POOL?]*M -> [FC -> RELU]*K -> FC

Having more than one layers of CONV->RELU pair before pooling improves learning complex features. Try with N=2 instead of 1.

Some other suggestions:

1. While you are preparing your data reduce it to smaller size than 128x64. Try same size as the MNIST data ..

   `image = tf.reshape(image, [28, 28, 1])`
2. If your eye/noeye image is color, then convert it to greyscale and normalize the values to unity range. You can do this using numpy or tf, here is how using numpy

grayscale-->

```
  img = np.dot(np.array(img, dtype='float32'), [[0.2989],[0.5870],[0.1140]])
```

normalize-->

```
 mean = np.mean(img, dtype='float32')
 std = np.std(img, dtype='float32', ddof=1)
 if std < 1e-4: std = 1.
 img = (img - mean) / std
```

Comment: Um.... I tried to upload loss and accuracy graph.. It said I need reputation(?) to upload the graph.. Anyway the accuracy when I trained with MNIST was 94%. I will post the whole code as soon as possible!

Comment: Yeah probably because you are a new user. Yes certainly post the code.

Comment: Since you are always getting same output 0, I strongly suspect that your filter values are never changing and you can check that by doing statistics on say W1 (like max, min after each iteration). May i also recommend that when you are reshaping your image then reduce it even smaller to 

       image = tf.reshape(image, [28, 28, 1])

Comment: Thanks you very much! It helps a lot :)